# Second dropdown list is not filtering

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am making an application , that allows the user to select a service from a list of services and an employee from a list of employees. When a user selects a service , the dropdownlist for the employees must automatically filter to show the employees that can perform that service or have that skill. For example if a customer selects a haircut , only employees whose skill is a haircut must filter into the dropdown list. I will show you my code , note : i do not want to create a relationship between service and employee.

The first dropdownlist is populating but not the second dropdownlist.If i hard code values into the Service Required dropdownlist, the filter works. If i populate the Service Required dropdownlist with values from the Service Table, the filter does not work Please view my code below

```
 public class EmployeeSkillVM
{
    public string ServiceRequired { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeChoice { get; set; }
}

 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Service> ServiceList = db.Services.ToList();
        ViewBag.ServiceList = new SelectList(ServiceList, "ServiceID", "ServiceName");
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult GetEmpList(string ServiceRequired)
    {
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        List<Employee> EmpList = db.Employees.Where(x => x.Skills == ServiceRequired).ToList();
        return Json(EmpList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }

 @model SkillFiltering.Models.EmployeeSkillVM
 @{
  ViewBag.Title = "Index";
  }

 <h2>Index</h2>
```

//This works

```
     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ServiceRequired,
     new List<SelectListItem>
{
 new SelectListItem {Text="--Select Country--" },
 new SelectListItem {Text="Shave" },
 new SelectListItem {Text="Massage" },
 new SelectListItem {Text="Haircut" }
 }, new { @class = "Select Item" })
```

//This does not work

```
  @if (ViewBag.ServiceList != null)
    {
     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ServiceRequired, ViewBag.ServiceList as SelectList, "--Select Country--", new { @class = "form-control" })
    }


 </div>


 <div class="form-group">
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EmployeeChoice, new SelectList(" "), "--Select State--", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ServiceRequired").change(function () {
        $.get("/Home2/GetEmpList", { ServiceRequired: $("#ServiceRequired").val() }, function (data) {
            $("#EmployeeChoice").empty();
            $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                $("#EmployeeChoice").append("<option value='" + row.EmployeeID + "'>" + row.EmployeeName + "</option>")
            });
        });
    })
});
 </script>
```

Comment: add an "alert('test')" in the loop to see its getting there

Comment: can you please show me where do i add that exactly

Comment: before $.each(data, function (index, row) {

Comment: What value you get in`ServiceRequired` ? You have three Sam's value in Employee database table?

Comment: what is `EmployeeSkillVM`? your Index action method didn't send any EmployeeSkillVM to view.

Answer (score 1):

you use `#ServiceRequired` for get the desire input for the second drop down list but you did not use `#ServiceRequired` as a  ID for the first drop down or u may use it as a css class `ServiceRequired`

Answer (score 0):

Inside your View, replace DropDowns with this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ServiceRequired, new SelectList(ViewBag.ServiceList, "ServiceID", "ServiceName"), "- Please Select -", new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EmployeeChoice, new SelectList(" "), "--Select State--", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

And your Index Action method will be:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Service> ServiceList = db.Services.ToList();
        ViewBag.ServiceList = ServiceList;
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Dear @GhulamMasudh, I reproduced your code and managed to build and run the above code successfully.